# base containning empty set

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Can base of a topology contain the empty set?

Is there any example of such a topology?

I am looking for one but I failed to construct one.

Comment: Why could a base of a topology not contain the empty set?

Comment: For example base of a metric topology does not contain empty set. I can't  find an example where it does.

Comment: A base $\mathcal{B}$ of a topological space $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is simply a subset of $\mathcal{T}$ such that each $U\in\mathcal{T}$ can be written as a union of elements of $\mathcal{B}$. You can always put the empty set in there (but you never have to).

Comment: @B.Pasternak don't you actually need the empty set? if it isn't in your base how will you write it as a union of elements in your base?

Comment: I would say that the empt set is the empty union. But maybe that isn't right, and what I said was too strong, so let's just put it in there (it doesn't make a difference for what the OP is asking).

Comment: fair enough, it doesn't really matter that much either way cause you can either think of it as an empty union or just throw it into the base